# How to fast change image brightness with python + OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing

I have a sequence of images. I need to average brightness of these images.

**First example** (very slow):

```
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg') #load rgb image
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #convert it to hsv

for x in range(0, len(hsv)):
    for y in range(0, len(hsv[0])):
        hsv[x, y][2] += value

img = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imwrite("image_processed.jpg", img)
```

**Second example** (quickly)

```
hsv += value
```

This example very fast but it changes all values HSV (I need to change only V (brightness))

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`Slice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) to select just the third channel and then modify those elements -

```
hsv[:,:,2] += value
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Gives some weird image as output after increasing brightness.

Comment: @GauravRaj You might be getting overflow. If so, you might need to use clipping : [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html). Also, just a reminder that this is working on the HSV side. So, you would need to do those RGB to HSV and back conversions.

Comment: Yes I did all that. BGR to HSV, Then hsv[:,:,2] += 50, Then np.clip, finally HSV to BGR. Still no luck.

Comment: @GauravRaj [`This`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822375/python-opencv-increasing-image-brightness-without-overflowing-uint8-array) should help out. To set the limiting value, you might want to read up on [`HSV Wiki`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

Comment: Hi, I simply applied opencv method to bgr image - cv2.add(inputImage, np.array([50.0])) increase brightness by 50.0

Comment: @GauravRaj Consider posting a new question if your queries have not been resolved, putting together all the details and linking to the relevant Q&As.

Comment: @Santhosh `hsv[:,:,2] -= value`?

Comment: @Divakar will cause underflow negative number in case the `V channel` values are less the `value`. Already tried

Comment: @Santhosh Follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822375/python-opencv-increasing-image-brightness-without-overflowing-uint8-array

Comment: @Divakar trying it, not able getting the logic straight

Comment: @Santhosh Post a new question.

Answer (score 82):

I know this question is a bit old, but I thought I might post the complete solution that worked for me (takes care of the overflow situation by saturating at 255):

```
def increase_brightness(img, value=30):
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)

    lim = 255 - value
    v[v > lim] = 255
    v[v <= lim] += value

    final_hsv = cv2.merge((h, s, v))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(final_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    return img
```

This can be used as follows:

```
frame = increase_brightness(frame, value=20)
```

Comment: Clear, easy to read and effective. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: I get this error error: (-215:Assertion failed) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function 'merge' any help?

Comment: Thanks this was perfect for my needs today!

Comment: Why are you using `v > lim` in the subscript? Doesn't that return a bool?

Answer (score 29):

The other answers suggest doing the saturation "by hand" using all kinds of numpy magic, but you can also use [cv2.add()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga10ac1bfb180e2cfda1701d06c24fdbd6) and let OpenCV handle that for you:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.read('image.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
value = 42 #whatever value you want to add
cv2.add(hsv[:,:,2], value, hsv[:,:,2])
image = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imwrite('out.png', image)
```

Comment: Far and away the best answer.  I was reading the other answers wondering why no one was doing what you suggested.  Sadly this answer was at the bottom.  The accepted answer is subject to 8 bit overflow and the helpful comment about cv2.add won't evenly brighten an image depending on colors.  This answer does it right.

Comment: I tried this code but shows TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'dst' at cv2.add().

Answer (score 13):

This was my solution to both increase and decrease brightness. Was having some error issues with a couple of the other answers. Function takes in a positive or negative value and alters brightness.

example in code

```
img = cv2.imread(path_to_image)
img = change_brightness(img, value=30) #increases
img = change_brightness(img, value=-30) #decreases
```

function being called

```
def change_brightness(img, value=30):
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
    v = cv2.add(v,value)
    v[v > 255] = 255
    v[v < 0] = 0
    final_hsv = cv2.merge((h, s, v))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(final_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
return img
```

Answer (score 9):

Iterating over the whole image to make changes is not a very scalable option in opencv, Opencv provides a lot of methods and functions to perform the arithmetic operations on the given image.

You may simply split the converted HSV image in the individual channels and then process the V channel accordingly as:

```
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg') #load rgb image
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #convert it to hsv

h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
v += 255
final_hsv = cv2.merge((h, s, v))

img = cv2.cvtColor(final_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imwrite("image_processed.jpg", img)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def change_brightness(img, alpha, beta):
   return cv2.addWeighted(img, alpha, np.zeros(img.shape, img.dtype),0, beta)
```

Here alpha & beta are input parameters. Each pixel of the input image will change according to this formula.

```
 alpha(pixel_value) + beta.
```

Lower value of alpha like 2 or 3 is good

Comment: I tried to change beta but the result didn't change, so, what it should do exactly.

Answer (score 3):

## Fastest?

For raw speed, just add a positive or negative integer to the original BGR image is probably the fastest. But you'll want to use an OpenCV function to avoid overflows. [convertScaleAbs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga3460e9c9f37b563ab9dd550c4d8c4e7d) is a good choice. We use the reference "mandrill" image from USC SIPI:

[image]

```
import cv2

def fast_brightness(input_image, brightness):
    ''' input_image:  color or grayscale image
        brightness:  -255 (all black) to +255 (all white)

        returns image of same type as input_image but with
        brightness adjusted'''
    img = input_image.copy()
    cv2.convertScaleAbs(img, img, 1, brightness)
    return img

img = cv2.imread('mandrill.tiff',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', fast_brightness(img, 100))
```

which gives (for brightness value of 100)

[image]

## Like Photoshop

For a brightness function more like Photoshop, The Gimp, or other image processing programs, you can use a function similar to [@md-hanif-ali-sohag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55875602/9705687) or the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50053219/9705687):

```
def photoshop_brightness(input_img, brightness = 0):
    ''' input_image:  color or grayscale image
        brightness:  -127 (all black) to +127 (all white)

            returns image of same type as input_image but with
            brightness adjusted

    '''
    img = input_img.copy()
    if brightness != 0:
        if brightness > 0:
            shadow = brightness
            highlight = 255
        else:
            shadow = 0
            highlight = 255 + brightness
        alpha_b = (highlight - shadow)/255
        gamma_b = shadow

        cv2.convertScaleAbs(input_img, img, alpha_b, gamma_b)

    return img
```

## Timing

I timed it for 1,000 iterations of running each function. And surprisingly, the times are nearly identical

```
elapsed fast_brightness [sec]:       0.8595983982086182
elapsed photoshop_brightness [sec]:  0.8565976619720459
```

Comment: "And surprisingly, the times are nearly identical" I don't think it is surprising. The "fancy" version of the code makes the same call to copy the image, does O(1) operations to compute the appropriate alpha and gamma values, and then (assuming `brightness != 0`) makes the same `convertScaleAbs` call to iterate over the pixels.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel. Point well taken. Some of the extra operations in the "fancy" version are pretty cheap computationally. The "fast" version has multiplication by factor of 1 and "fancy" version has multiplication by something other than 1. if `convertScaleAbs` was a little more optimized for corner cases, maybe the "fast" version would be faster.

Answer (score 2):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

increase = 100

v = image[:, :, 2]
v = np.where(v <= 255 - increase, v + increase, 255)
image[:, :, 2] = v

image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

cv2.imshow('Brightness', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What is `increase`?

Comment: @mLstudent33 It's the amount of the desired brightness increase. I've edited my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is useful for someone

@Divakar answer [Python, OpenCV: Increasing image brightness without overflowing UINT8 array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822375/python-opencv-increasing-image-brightness-without-overflowing-uint8-array)

```
mImage = cv2.imread('image1.jpg')

hsvImg = cv2.cvtColor(mImage,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

value = 0

vValue = hsvImg[...,2]
hsvImg[...,2] = np.where((255-vValue)<value,255,vValue+value)

plt.subplot(111), plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(hsvImg,cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB))
plt.title('brightened image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

To decrease the brightness

```
mImage = cv2.imread('image1.jpg')

hsvImg = cv2.cvtColor(mImage,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# decreasing the V channel by a factor from the original
hsvImg[...,2] = hsvImg[...,2]*0.6

plt.subplot(111), plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(hsvImg,cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB))
plt.title('brightened image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be too old but I use cv.covertTo which works for me

```
Mat resultBrightImage;    
origImage.convertTo(resultBrightImage, -1, 1, percent); // Where percent = (int)(percent_val/100)*255, e.g., percent = 50 to increase brightness by 50%
```

convertTo uses saturate_cast at the end to avoid any overflows. I don't use Python and the above is in C++ but I hope it is easily convertible in Python and hope it helps

Comment: I'm surprised this is the only answer that mentions `cv::Mat::convertTo()`.  Works beautifully, and does the work in a single API call.

Comment: the MAT functions are not available in Python. However, [convertScaleAbs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga3460e9c9f37b563ab9dd550c4d8c4e7d) is similar and is available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to change your desired [brightness or contrast using C++](https://www.life2coding.com/brightness-and-contrast-control-using-opencv-c/) just like the same way you do it on photoshop or other similar photo editing software.

```
def apply_brightness_contrast(input_img, brightness = 255, contrast = 127):
    brightness = map(brightness, 0, 510, -255, 255)
    contrast = map(contrast, 0, 254, -127, 127)

    if brightness != 0:
        if brightness > 0:
            shadow = brightness
            highlight = 255
        else:
            shadow = 0
            highlight = 255 + brightness
        alpha_b = (highlight - shadow)/255
        gamma_b = shadow

        buf = cv2.addWeighted(input_img, alpha_b, input_img, 0, gamma_b)
    else:
        buf = input_img.copy()

    if contrast != 0:
        f = float(131 * (contrast + 127)) / (127 * (131 - contrast))
        alpha_c = f
        gamma_c = 127*(1-f)

        buf = cv2.addWeighted(buf, alpha_c, buf, 0, gamma_c)

    cv2.putText(buf,'B:{},C:{}'.format(brightness,contrast),(10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    return buf

def map(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max):
    return int((x-in_min) * (out_max-out_min) / (in_max-in_min) + out_min)
```

After that you need to call the functions by creating trackbar using `cv2.createTrackbar()` and call that above functions with proper parameters as well. In order to map the brightness values which ranges from -255 to +255 and contrast values -127 to +127, you can use that `map()` function. You can check the full details of about [python implementation here](https://www.life2coding.com/change-brightness-and-contrast-of-images-using-opencv-python/).

Answer (score 1):

An OpenCV image is a numpy array of data type numpy.uint8. The problem with adding an arbitrary value to any of the channels is that an overflow can easily occur. For example, numpy.uint8(255) + numpy.uint8(1) = 0. To avoid this problem, we first convert our BGR image to HLS. Then we convert our HLS image (a numpy.uint8 array) to numpy.int16, we add a lightness value to the second channel, push any entries above 255 in the lightness channel down to 255, and push any entries below 0 up to 0. Now all the values v in the lightness channel satisfy 0 <= v <=255. At this point we can convert back to numpy.uint8, and then convert to BGR.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Negative values for the percentage parameter are allowed
def increase_brightness(bgr_img, percentage):
    hls_img = cv.cvtColor(bgr_img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
    value = np.int16(255*percentage/100)
    hls_arr_16bit = np.int16(hls_img)
    hls_arr_16bit[:,:,1] += value

    if percentage > 0:
        hls_arr_16bit[:,:,1] = np.where(hls_arr_16bit[:,:,1] <= 255, hls_arr_16bit[:,:,1], np.int16(255))
    elif percentage < 0:
        hls_arr_16bit[:,:,1] = np.where(hls_arr_16bit[:,:,1] >= 0, hls_arr_16bit[:,:,1], np.int16(0))

    hls_img = np.uint8(hls_arr_16bit)
    brightened_bgr_img = cv.cvtColor(hls_img, cv.COLOR_HLS2BGR)
    return brightened_bgr_img

img = cv.imread('path\\to\\image.jpg')
mod_img = increase_brightness(img)
cv.imwrite('path\\to\\modified_image.jpg', mod_img)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this shouldn't be so hard and there to adjust the brightness of an image. Also, there are already plenty of great answers. I would like to enhance the answer of @BillGrates, so it works on grayscale images and with decreasing the brightness: `value = -255` creates a black image whereas `value = 255` a white one.

```py
def adjust_brightness(img, value):
    num_channels = 1 if len(img.shape) < 3 else 1 if img.shape[-1] == 1 else 3
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) if num_channels == 1 else img
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)

    if value >= 0:
        lim = 255 - value
        v[v > lim] = 255
        v[v <= lim] += value
    else:
        value = int(-value)
        lim = 0 + value
        v[v < lim] = 0
        v[v >= lim] -= value

    final_hsv = cv2.merge((h, s, v))

    img = cv2.cvtColor(final_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) if num_channels == 1 else img
    return img
```

Answer (score 0):

HSV channels are uint8 type, hue value range is [0, 179]. Therefore, when add with a large number or a negative number, Python returns a garbage result. So in hue channel we need to change to int16 type and then back to uint8 type. On saturation (S), and value (V) channels, the same problem occurs, so we need to check the value before adding or subtracting.

Here is my solution for random hue, saturation, and value shifting. It base on [@alkasm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49697944/10151497), and [@bill-grates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47427398/10151497) code sample.

```
def shift_channel(c, amount):
   if amount > 0:
        lim = 255 - amount
        c[c >= lim] = 255
        c[c < lim] += amount
    elif amount < 0:
        amount = -amount
        lim = amount
        c[c <= lim] = 0
        c[c > lim] -= amount
    return c

rand_h, rand_s, rand_v = 50, 50, 50
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(img_hsv)
# Random shift hue
shift_h = random.randint(-rand_h, rand_h)
h = ((h.astype('int16') + shift_h) % 180).astype('uint8')
# Random shift saturation
shift_s = random.randint(-rand_s, rand_s)
s = shift_channel(s, shift_s)
# Random shift value
shift_v = random.randint(-rand_v, rand_v)
v = shift_channel(v, shift_v)
shift_hsv = cv2.merge([h, s, v])
print(shift_h, shift_s, shift_v)
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(shift_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
```