# OpenCV/Python: Error in cv2.add() to add a number to image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm using OpenCV/Python and I'm trying to add a number to image.

My code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('messi.jpg',0)
img2 = img
img2 = cv2.add(img2, np.uint8([50]))
```

I got the next error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type2 == CV_64F && (sz2.height == 1 || sz2.heigh
t == 4)) in cv::arithm_op, file C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-stati
c\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp, line 1989
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lab3_examples.py", line 27, in <module>
    img2 = cv2.add(img, np.uint8([50]))
cv2.error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core
\src\arithm.cpp:1989: error: (-215) type2 == CV_64F && (sz2.height == 1 || sz2.h
eight == 4) in function cv::arithm_op
```

The image I'm using is `messi.jpg` [image]

Instead, if I use `img2 = np.add(img2, np.uint8([50]))` intensities that pass the value 255 the `value % 255 result`, e.g. `260%255=4` the pixel's value is set to 4 instead of 255. As a result, white pixels are turned to black!

Here is the faulty resulted image. [image]

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

In C++ for this purpose *saturate_cast(...)* is used.
In Python simply

`img2 = cv2.add(img2, 50)`

will do, if you want to increase brightness for gray-scale image. If implied to colored, color balance will be shifted. For colored image, to save the balance, good answer is by *Alex, Bill Grates:*

*[How to fast change image brightness with python + OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609098/how-to-fast-change-image-brightness-with-python-opencv)*

The only remark - next part of code are not nessessary:

*v[v > 255] = 255*

*v[v < 0] = 0*
in my case (Python3,Opencv4).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest convert the BGR image to HSV image:

```
hsv= cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Then split the channels using:

```
h_channel, s_channel, v_channel = cv2.split(hsv)
```

Now play with the `h_channel`:

```
h_channel + = 20  #---You can try any other value as well---
```

Now merge the channels back together again:

```
merged = cv2.merge((h_channel , s_channel , v_channel ))
```

Finally convert the image back to BGR and display it:

```
Final_image = cv2.cvtColor(merged, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imshow('Final output', Final_image)
```

You will see an enhanced or a dimmed image depending on the value you add.

Hope it helps.... :D

Comment: This a good example, but I want to explain to my students the `RGB` channels so there is no need to involve them with `HSV`. Thank you anyway!

Comment: In that case, you can try out the same case using RGB image. Split the image to separate channels and add an integer to it merge the channels and then see the result ...Simple    ..  :D