# Numpy: How to prevent circular looping to highest value when subtracting from the least value

Tags: python, numpy

```
image = cv2.imread('black.jpg')[:,:,0] # let's just take the red channel alone for brevity
print(image[75:85,155:165]) # print middle 10x10
# output: [[0,0,0,....],...]
```

I want subtract 1 from all pixel intensity. And yes, I  definitely do not want 0s to become 255s. I just want them to stay as 0.

```
print(image[75:85,155:165]-1)
# output: [[255,255,255,....],...]

print(np.array(image[75:85,155:165])-1)
# output: [[255,255,255,....],...]

print(np.array(image[75:85,155:165], dtype='float32')-1)
# output: [[-1.,-1.,-1.,....],...]
```

I can convert the last one back to `uint8` after `.clip(0,255)` but that doesn't feel like the right way of doing it. Is there a way to directly do it (without casting and if conditions which might not be efficient for parallel processing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is `np.where` with mask:

```
grey_new = np.where(image == 0, 0, image - 1)
```

more info you can find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37822699/7430165), and [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) documentation.

Comment: this should be faster than subtracting and then pick things equal to 255 and making them 0, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

One easy option would be:

```
image[75:85,155:165] - 1 * (image[75:85,155:165] > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you remove 1 to all values, only the 0 values will become 255. What you can do, then, is simply to put those back to 0 :

```
a = np.array(image[75:85,155:165])-1
a[a==255] = 0
```