# OpenCV & Python: How to decrease brightness using binary mask?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I would like to darken one image based on the mask of an edge-detected second image.

**Image 1: Original (greyscale) image**

[image]

**Image 2: Edge detected (to be used as mask)**

[image]

**Image 3: Failed example showing cv2.subtract processing**

[image]

In my **failed** example (Image 3), I subtracted the white pixels (255) from the original image but what I want to do is **DARKEN** the original image based on a mask of the edge detected image.

In this article: [How to fast change image brightness with python + OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609098/how-to-fast-change-image-brightness-with-python-opencv), Bill Gates describes how he converts the image to HSV, splits out then modifies *Value*, and then finally merges back. This seems like a reasonable approach but I only want to modify the *Value* where the mask is white i.e. the edge exists.

Ultimately, I am trying to *enhance* the edge of a low resolution thermal video stream in a similar way to the FLIR One VividIR technology.

I believe that I've made it really far as a complete novice to image processing, OpenCV and Python but after days now of trying just about every function OpenCV offers, I've got myself stuck.

Comment: Gray scale images only?

Comment: @David Could you show us an example image of your thermal video stream use case? That might make it easier to workout a solution.

Comment: Anon No, thermal image has three channels but I know how to split them.

Ganesh Happy to share images/video if you're still interested. I'm basically fitting my DJI Mavic Pro drone with a night vision (composite thermal and NIR) capability without the multi-thousand price tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
## get the edge coordinates
pos = np.where(edge >0)
## divide 
img[pos] //=2
```

Comment: It may have been brief and, tbh, I don't fully understand why it works, but it certainly works!! Two days ... two days I've been working on doing that and it ends up being two lines of code. You guys are just fantastic!

I'm guessing that the numpy function ends up with a boolean array of the same size where each instance of >0 becomes True. Then the 2nd line must carry out a division (such strange syntax, //=2) on the original array only when the second array (the mask) holds a True. Very clever and works perfectly.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre They guys think the answer is too short, and criticize without checking whether it works or not ....

Comment: Maybe you could add more context around this code. It seems OP understood you, but not the others. My trick in this case is to provide fake simple data for a standalone code snippet that anyone can paste and see that it works. I also think that you're collateral of now deleted even shorter answer which looks like yours but with some smartass comments added.

Comment: or maybe they just don't like soccer :)