# How can I change colors in OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv

On the left is the original image. On the right is a color-distorted image. How do I color the left as the right image?[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZkH7.jpg)

Comment: How did you distort it? Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49697363/shifting-hsv-pixel-values-in-python-using-numpy - this is the solution to my problem