# Is there any way to increase the brightness of a video in python?

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-processing, brightness

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61022201/11742812) is the way to increase the brightness of an image. However, adding this piece of code to a video creates an unstable and flickering video. Is there any alternative to increase the brightness of a video where the brightness would be stable throughout the video after getting increased?

Comment: Applying that code to a video frame-by-frame will naturally cause flickering. You can of course lift the brightness of all frames by the same constant amount, which would not flicker, but you would also need to figure out that constant amount by hand, and it might blow out some scenes that are already bright. You could also scan through the entire video to figure out the brightening parameters, then use those.

Comment: @nathancy I have used the CLAHE method to adjust the contrast but I don't think it applies to brightness.