# OpenCV cv2.add TypeError with arguments

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to run the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49280629/15404050) to make an image brighter.

The code in question is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# as people point out in comments, cv2.read() from the original
# code no longer works
image = cv2.imread('image.png')   
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
value = 42 #whatever value you want to add
cv2.add(hsv[:,:,2], value, hsv[:,:,2])
image = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imwrite('out.png', image)
```

On the line `cv2.add(hsv[:,:,2], value, hsv[:,:,2])` I get the following error

`TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'dst'`

This happens with any input image I've tried and someone else posted the same issue as a comment to that answer. How can this be fixed?

EDIT: as people have pointed out you won't be able to run `cv2.read` above. You'll ne

Comment: Try using `cv2.imread` instead of `cv2.read` and be sure to use an absolute path to the image.

Comment: Yeah I'm doing that. The problem line is definitely the `cv2.add()`. I've viewed the images, checked the arrays, etc.

Comment: No, you're not, at least not according to the "code in question". In it's present form that will end in error, since there's no such thing as `cv2.read`.

Comment: The problem is `hsv[:,:,2]` as a destination -- that has step size set to skip the other channels, and while OpenCV can use that as an input, it can't use it as an output.

Comment: Ok I've updated with the change from cv2.read to .imread, which is true ofcourse

Comment: I'd just do `cv2.add(hsv, (0,0,value,0), hsv)`. NB it has to be a tuple with 4 values, so it gets recognised as a scalar.

Comment: @DanMašek working - pls put in an answer so I can accept